# Can't open bootstrap modal from table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 table and I'd like to open different modals from different rows. Each row has a different id with php. The ids work perfect, but the modal doesn't show up.
This is how it looks like:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">User</th>
            <th scope="col">Premium</th>
            <th scope="col">Admin</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr class="clickable-row" id="clickable-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" 
                   data-href='#userModal-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' data-toggle="modal" 
                   data-target="#userModal-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $levelstr; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $admin; ?></td>
            </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The modals:

```
<!-- User modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="userModal-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userModalLabel-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="userModalLabel-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the script, I'm trying to trigger to open the modal:

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    console.log('#userModal-' + id);
    $('#userModal-' + id).modal('show');
});
```

This is what I got from the console.log:

```
#userModal-2
#userModal-3
...
```

And these ids are correct, but for some reason the modal doesn't show up.

Comment: 1st: check if there is a model with id exists `console.log($('#userModal-' + id).length);` it should be 1 .. 2nd: if its exists check if  any css/styling affected it to be hidden

Comment: Looks like it doesn't exist. It always gives '0'. But I don't understand why. The ids are correct.

Comment: Found the problem. The problem was that I put the modal outside of my while loop and that's why it didnt get the id. That console.log helped a lot, thank you very much! If you write it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: *No need for an answer you answered it yourself  :)*.. You're totally welcome anytime .. Have a great day :-) @randomdude

Comment: Thank you, you too! :D